# Why doesn't my argument-counting validation work?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

Below is a snippet of my code in which I am trying to do a sanity check against user's command-line arguments.

My program should accept only two arguments from the user; beside the program name; or otherwise it will spit out a **USAGE** message for program's usage.

The issue is I can't figure out why the program won't proceed when it is supplied with the desired number of arguments?!

The code keeps returning back the **Usage Message** no matter how many arguments out there; even when its true to have two of them; any thought about what should I do?

```
## Perfome a sanity check against command-line arguments
for arg in sys.argv:
    if len(arg) != 3:
        print(f'Usage: dna.py <DNA database CSV file> <STR sequence text file>')
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Why are you looping over `sys.argv`?

Comment: You are testing the string lengths of your command line arguments (each, including the name of the script itself, must be three characters long). This is clearly not the intention. You want to be testing `len(sys.argv)`, without any loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot dear (alaniwi) for your contribution. What you've pointed out was too helpful for me, the code did its job, so thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the for loop is not necessary you just need something like this:

```
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
   print("Your usage")
```

You can always use `argparse` standard module, which helps you to build a user-friendly command line program.

Comment: Agreed, but I suspect the OP would benefit from an actual example of how `argparse` can be used here.

Comment: Yeas. `argparse` makes the life easier